# for how long data in Isolated storage is persistent

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, persistent

I have read that data stored in Isolated Storage in wp7 is permanent.But I am a little confused about the term 'permanent'. I don't have wp7 device so I can't check this on a real device. I tried the emulator and everything is working fine until I close my emulator. I want to know if the same problem exists on the real device when the application is closed or the device is switched off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the device, the IsolatedStorage will keep your data, until you uninstall/delete the application. When you use an emulator, the "installed app" remains only until you close the emulator. Closing your emulator is equivalent to deleting your application.

Comment: Thanks. Is it necessary to save the changes to the Isolated Storage in the Application_Closing event in App.xaml.cs

Comment: As @Santhu said, it is not needed. But, there might be an issue where your application is just deactivated and due to unavailability of resources, the OS decides to tombstone your application. In such as case, I would recommend to save the ApplicationSettings when you find all the necessary data acquired.

Comment: I meant is there is no extra things are required to in application closing. But after your storing of the data, you have save the isolated storage to make it to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

In device Isolated Storage data is stored **till the application is Uninstalled**.
Whether it may IsolatedStorage data or Application Settings.

Comment: thanks, but can you please tell me if it is necessary to save the changes made to the Isolted Storage in the event of Application_Closing?

Comment: Unless you are intending to allow the user to keep their saved data, even if they uninstall your app.

In this case you'll need to also save the data to "the cloud" (a web service)- allowing the user to download their data back into their isolated storage if/when they reinstall the app.

In that way, the data is truly permanent and may be extremely useful for some users, especially if they lose their phone/wipe it/send it to be repaired (they often wipe your phone) and have to reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using windows phone instead of emulator IS is persistent. But in emulator the story is different refer this question [Automatic login process in Windows Phone 7.1 application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9329687/1099894)