# How to make IsolatedStorageSettings persist even after the device is turned off?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage

First page of the my application requests the login ID and password which I store using isolated storage. I want my application to remember the login credentials even if the device is switched off i.e once the user logs in, the application should store the login values and on a user's next visit the login page should not appear and directly the second page should be displayed.

Can anybody help me do this???

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using IsolatedStorageSettings or an IsolatedStorageFile?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts: M using  IsolatedStorageFile

Comment: And are you using the emulator or an actual phone?

Comment: @PaulAnnetts: emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the question: "[for how long data in Isolated storage is persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476772/for-how-long-data-in-isolated-storage-is-persistent)".

If you restart the Windows Phone emulator it is equivalent to deleting the application. This does not happen on a real phone.

Answer (score 0):

You should call [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in order to persist the changes to the settings class.